# chat.facebook.com doesn't send zero byte at the end of the cross domain policy file response

Tags: facebook, xmpp

We are implementing a Facebook application where AS3(XIFF 3.1.0 lib) is used to login to Facebook chat so that the App may send some notifications to the user's friends. At this point we come across a problem regarding a cross domain policy file required by Adobe. The thing is, when the request to get a cross domain policy file from chat.facebook.com (using
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://chat.facebook.com:5222") ) is answered from an IP address other than 69.171.241.10 the zero byte terminating the policy file is missing in the response from the server(e.g. 173.252.107.17:5222). 
According to Wireshark the flow looks like below.

**Request:**

```
<policy-file-request/>
\000
```

**Response:**

```
<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"5222\"/>
```

According to the Adobe recommendation "The server must send a null byte to terminate a policy file, and may thereafter close the connection; if the server does not close the connection, Flash Player or AIR does so upon receiving the terminating null byte."

Assumption: As a result the flash player considers that no policy file is received and doesn't process xmpp login to Facebook chat.

If the assumption is correct then it looks like a Facebook bug.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be a Facebook bug. I've verified this by performing a Wireshark link against the Openfire XMPP server (which works correctly). Have reported the bug with FB:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/707541335928781

Comment: I had already reported a bug but forgot to share the link to this topic. Facebook support asked me to provide more details regarding the issue which is already done. So could you please add your comments under this issue so that we'll concentrate our efforts to the report which is in progress to be resolved. 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/158215717712948

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Good News!!!**

Facebook has fixed the bug.